# Increasing Ajax request timeout in ExtJs

Tags: ajax, extjs4, timeout

Is there one single configuration in ExtJs library to increase Ajax request timeout?

I have tried following two configurations but neither helped:

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.Connection, {
    timeout: 60000
});

Ext.Ajax.timeout = 60000;
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I used the 2 that you mentioned, but also had to override these:

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.proxy.Ajax, { timeout: 60000 });
Ext.override(Ext.form.action.Action, { timeout: 60 });
```

**Update for ExtJS 5:**

It looks like you now need to set the Ext.Ajax timeout using `setTimeout()` for ExtJS 5+, instead of just setting the property:

```
Ext.Ajax.setTimeout(60000);
```

Comment: What about the time limit? I'm working on a route calculation and I think it will take a lot to finish...

Comment: Where did you put this?

Answer (score 6):

I had to do below one :

```
Ext.Ajax.timeout= 60000; 
Ext.override(Ext.form.Basic, { timeout: Ext.Ajax.timeout / 1000 });
Ext.override(Ext.data.proxy.Server, { timeout: Ext.Ajax.timeout });
Ext.override(Ext.data.Connection, { timeout: Ext.Ajax.timeout });
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found this is the best change for ExtJS 4 (tested on 4.2.3):

```
// Connection uses its own timeout value hardcoded in ExtJS - we remove it so that Ext.data.Connection will then
// fallback to using Ext.Ajax.timeout, thus giving a single place for setting the timeout
// Bonus: you can change this at runtime
Ext.define('Monitoring.overrides.Connection', {
  override: 'Ext.data.Connection',
  constructor: function() {
    delete this.timeout;
    this.callParent(arguments);
  }
});
Ext.define('Monitoring.overrides.ProxyServer', {
  override: 'Ext.data.proxy.Server',
  constructor: function() {
    delete this.timeout;
    this.callParent(arguments);
  }
});
```

Now you can use Ext.Ajax.timeout and it will change all the AJAX calls (don't know about form submission).

Answer (score 1):

This solution doesn't work for me:

```
Ext.Ajax.timeout = 60000
```

Then i found an other solution from ExtJS Docs (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.5.0/classic/Ext.Ajax.html). It is the same solution as @kevhender mentioned before. This works for me (ExtJS version 7.5):

```
Ext.Ajax.setTimeout(60000)
```